# How to save EXIF metadata in WordPress database?

Tags: database, post-meta

I have a function that gets retrieves image EXIF metadata and displays it on attachment edit page.

```
function wp_read_image_metadata_exif( $file ) {
if ( ! file_exists( $file ) ) {
    return false;
}

list( , , $image_type ) = wp_getimagesize( $file );

if ( is_callable( 'iptcparse' ) ) {
    wp_getimagesize( $file, $info );

    if ( ! empty( $info['APP13'] ) ) {

        if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG
            && ! defined( 'WP_RUN_CORE_TESTS' )
        ) {
            $iptc = iptcparse( $info['APP13'] );
        } else {
            $iptc = @iptcparse( $info['APP13'] );
        }
        
        if ( ! empty( $iptc['2#090'][0] ) ) { // City.
            $meta['city'] = trim( $iptc['2#090'][0] );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $iptc['2#027'][0] ) ) { // Location Name.
            $meta['locationname'] = trim( $iptc['2#027'][0] );
        }
    }
}

return apply_filters( 'wp_read_image_metadata_exif', $meta, $file, $iptc );

}


function display_exif_fields ( $form_fields, $post ){

$type = get_post_mime_type( $post->ID );

$attachment_path = get_attached_file( $post->ID );

$metadata = wp_read_image_metadata_exif( $attachment_path );
$form_fields['city'] = array(
    'label' => 'City',
    'input' => 'text',
    'value' => $metadata['city'],
    'helps' => '',
);

$form_fields['locationname'] = array(
    'label' => 'Location name',
    'input' => 'text',
    'value' => $metadata['locationname'],
    'helps' => '',
);

return $form_fields;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'display_exif_fields', 10, 2 );
```

The metadata displays, but I can't handle it to save in WPDB. Following function does not bring any results:

```
function save_exif_fields( $post, $attachment ) {
    if( isset( $attachment['city'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'city', $attachment['city'] );

if( isset( $attachment['locationname'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'locationname', $attachment['locationname'] );

return $post;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'save_exif_fields', 10, 2 );
```

What should I change it the code to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the help from a guru on other forum. The following code add fields 'City' and 'Location name' to attachment edit page. Their values gets from IPTC metadata `(Tag: 90, Key: Iptc.Application2.City / Tag: 27, Key: Iptc.Application2.LocationName)` and automatically save it in db on image upload (Custom fields: '`city`' and '`locationname`'). The values can be modified manually on the same attachment edit page.

```
 function wp_read_image_metadata_exif( $file ) {
    if ( ! file_exists( $file ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    list( , , $image_type ) = wp_getimagesize( $file );

    if ( is_callable( 'iptcparse' ) ) {
        wp_getimagesize( $file, $info );

        if ( ! empty( $info['APP13'] ) ) {

            if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG
                && ! defined( 'WP_RUN_CORE_TESTS' )
            ) {
                $iptc = iptcparse( $info['APP13'] );
            } else {
                $iptc = @iptcparse( $info['APP13'] );
            }
            
            if ( ! empty( $iptc['2#090'][0] ) ) { // City.
                $meta['city'] = trim( $iptc['2#090'][0] );
            }
            if ( ! empty( $iptc['2#027'][0] ) ) { // Location Name.
                $meta['locationname'] = trim( $iptc['2#027'][0] );
            }
        }
    }

    return apply_filters( 'wp_read_image_metadata_exif', $meta, $file, $iptc );

 }

 function display_exif_fields ( $form_fields, $post ){
                
    $city = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'city', true );   
    
    $locationname = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'locationname', true );
       
    $form_fields['city'] = array(
      'label' => 'City',
      'input' => 'text',
      'value' => $city,
      'helps' => '',
    );
  
    $form_fields['locationname'] = array(
      'label' => 'Location name',
      'input' => 'text',
      'value' => $locationname,
      'helps' => '',
    );

    return $form_fields;
  }

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'display_exif_fields', 10, 2 );


function save_exif_fields( $post, $attachment ) {

    $array = [ 'city', 'locationname' ];
    foreach ( $array as $one ) {
      if ( ! empty( $attachment[ $one ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post[ 'ID' ], $one, $attachment[ $one ] );
      } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post[ 'ID' ], $one );
      }
    }

    return $post;   
 }

 add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'save_exif_fields', 10, 2 );


 add_action('added_post_meta', 'save_exif_fields_on_upload', 10, 4);

 function save_exif_fields_on_upload($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) {
        
    $type = get_post_mime_type( $post_id );

    $attachment_path = get_attached_file( $post_id );

    $metadata = wp_read_image_metadata_exif( $attachment_path );
        
    if($meta_key === '_wp_attachment_metadata') {   

        update_post_meta($post_id, 'city', $metadata['city']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'locationname', $metadata['locationname']);
           
        $attachment_meta = get_post_meta($post_id);
    }
 }
```